# Cannot input username into Custom super user Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I want to create a custom authentication for Django. Created a custom class and manager as well. I'm not able to run the command python manage.py createsuperuser with --username attribute. It says there's not parameter like that.

Without username it gives a value error of null Username. Please help.

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address')

        if not kwargs.get('username'):
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid username')

        account = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), username=kwargs.get('username')
        )

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

        account.is_admin = True
        account.save()

        return account

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FILEDS = ['username']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ''.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at writing your own management command to handle the custom user creation.

Comment: Could you please provide a useful link..? Is it really necessary that I should write a custom management command..? @KineticStack

Comment: I'm not sure it's 100% necessary, but it might be helpful in the future depending on what all you do with this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/